# Is online poker more technical than live poker?

Tags: poker-strategy

Coming from [this question](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/11721/resources-to-learn-poker-skill) about differentiation between technical and poker skills, I wonder if to know technical skills is fairly more close to be enough to be a winner in online than live poker.

Are poker skills still important to become a winner in online poker?

Answer (score 1):

in the broad scope of things, it's hard to define what you're referring to as "technical skills" in poker. what i mean by this is that there are too many ways this can be interpreted, since, as you no doubt know, with poker, the type of game and the elements involved in each can differ widely.

if you look at the literal definition of "technical skills" it's more or less defined as  "the abilities and knowledge that enable someone to perform certain functions". this definition does not help us as much as, once again, with poker, there are too many factors at play one needs to consider.

the game of poker is a game of skill. remember, you are still playing the game, no matter the variant, so it's important to know the game that you are playing.

the most skilled live player is not only using their poker playing skills but he/she is also using the environment. this is an environment they are comfortable with and most used to. within this environment, they are able to use their honed skills to watch close for any signs, or tells, with most of them being physical, that may indicate to them what their opponent has in their hand and/or what they are currently thinking about.

there is also an environment in online poker. it doesn't share all of the same physical types of tells against your opponent, but that doesn't mean it is without them. in fact, online poker introduces it's own types of tells. one of the most important tells to know about and to master is bet-sizing. coupled with the second most important, speed of play, you now have a set of tells against your opponent... or is it visa versa? your opponent actually has a set of tells against you, too! either way, these are skills that are present and evident in every online game.

one more thing i wanted to mention is the fact that the games being played do not change, but the ways you can play them vastly differ. if you consider that live you can play one table, well, technically large field MTTs can be auto-folded at low levels which can provide the opportunity for a player to "multi-table", but, for sake of discussion, we're to assume that live poker is limited to one table per player. in online poker, depending on the software as well as your (now understandingly important) skill and comfort level, a player can find themselves playing anywhere from 2 to 100+ tables at a time. this provides a whole new set of capabilities and introduces a skill requirement within the game it's self, but ultimately it still requires skills in poker to be effective.

further more, remembering the varied types of games involved, there are different play styles and strategies for each. some are even scientific! consider "ICM", or Independent Chip Model, generally confined to STT SNGs, tournaments, or final tables. these are proven mathematically and no doubt require poker skills to implement and master.

so, leaving "technical skills" defined as the literal definition, i'm going to re-word your question:

Are poker abilities and knowledge that enable someone to perform certain functions still important to become a winner in online poker?

now, the answer to the above question as well as the one you asked in your request:

> "Are poker skills still important to become a winner in online poker?"

**yes!**

Answer (score 0):

Live poker as well as online poker require a lot ofthe same poker skills.
Although their playstyles are different, the basic rules and strategies are similar.
The biggest difference is the speed of play. Unlike live poker, which is a bit more relaxed, online poker is a fast game, so players who are playing for the first time may feel a little difficult. If you want to know another difference, visit https://holdemgallery.com There is a lot of information about poker. You will get what you want. good luck

Comment: Can the writer disclose if they have an affiliation with the linked site? They have posted it at least twice, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

playing live will help you to be better at online, playing online will help you play live.the main skill you need live that is not used much online is the ability to read and understand tells. so live poker is a bit more complicated in that way. having said that there is a lot of the same context that you base decisions on rather live or online. like general observations of a player.does the player come in a lot preflop, does the player show a lot of garbage hands, is the player tight passive, loose aggressive etc.